# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element i tried this driver.implicitly_wait(20) but not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i have this problem

**i tried this**

```
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

but not working and same problem

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#user_username"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
```

**this shown after a website loaded**

i can't accesses to form
this is form link 
 **https://accounts.esri.com/en/login**

this is simple code

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    URL = 'https://accounts.esri.com/en/login'
    userName = 'test'
    passWord = 'test'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(URL)
    time.sleep(10)
    passWordInput = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#user_username')
    passWordInput.send_keys(userName)
    passWordInput = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#user_password')
    passWordInput.send_keys(passWord)
    buttonSignIn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#signIn')
    buttonSignIn.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This form is inside `<iframe>` and for browser it is different page so it can't find it. You have to use `switch_to.frame` to change frame and then you can search in this frame.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

URL = 'https://accounts.esri.com/en/login'

userName = 'test'
passWord = 'test'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(10)

f = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(f)

passWordInput = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#user_username')
passWordInput.send_keys(userName)

passWordInput = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#user_password')
passWordInput.send_keys(passWord)

buttonSignIn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#signIn')
buttonSignIn.click()

time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Sleeps are never a good practice. Instead use `EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()` to wait for the frame and then switch to it once it's available. See [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for more info.

Comment: @JeffC say it to OP - I only get its code and add needed code to resolve main problem :) I could put only this code without rest lines.

Comment: I'm saying it to both of you... :). When I answer a question, I make it a point to answer not only the question but also offer advice when I see that improvements can be made. It does no good to not correct bad practices and using sleeps is a universal bad practice.